# Inconsistent latex bibliographic references

Tags: natbib

I am having references appearing in different format each time. Sometimes it appear in the correct format (FirstnameFirstAuthor et al Year), and in other times it appear in different format (Firstauthor name second author name and thirdauthor name and year). You can see for the example below I am doing

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib} 

\begin{document}

First citation is appearing correctly \cite{chen2018effective}, Second is correct also 
     \cite{deng2019user}, while last one is appearing in incorrect format \cite{liang2021unsupervised}

\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}
\bibliography{bmc_article}

\end{document}
```

Here are the three bibs entries in the bmc_article.bib file :

```
@article{chen2018effective,
  title={Effective and efficient user account linkage across location based social networks},
  author={Chen, Wei and Yin, Hongzhi and Wang, Weiqing and Zhao, Lei and Zhou, Xiaofang},
  booktitle={2018 IEEE 34th International Conference on Data Engineering (ICDE)},
  pages={1085--1096},
  year={2018},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{deng2019user,
  title={A user identification algorithm based on user behavior analysis in social networks},
  author={Deng, Kaikai and Xing, Ling and Zheng, Longshui and Wu, Honghai and Xie, Ping and Gao, Feifei},
  journal={IEEE Access},
  volume={7},
  pages={47114--47123},
  year={2019},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{liang2021unsupervised,
  title={Unsupervised Large-Scale Social Network Alignment via Cross Network Embedding},
  author={Liang, Zhehan and Rong, Yu and Li, Chenxin and Zhang, Yunlong and Huang, Yue and Xu, Tingyang and Ding, Xinghao and Huang, Junzhou},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 30th ACM International Conference on Information \& Knowledge Management},
  pages={1008--1017},
  year={2021}
}
```

And this is the result I am obtaining
[image]

and here is the model1-num-names.bst file :
https://docdro.id/8l8VL89

Comment: if you show no code, it will be very hard to debug

Comment: the format of the citation is a consequence of the bib entries so the differences will be due to differences in the bib entries you have not shown

Comment: that's right thanks

Comment: I checked and found that the bib entries are all the same. What I  found is that when you cite the paper a second time, the format comes correct (at the second time), but still remains incorrect in the first citation

Comment: as I say if you don't post any code no one can help.  Fix your question so people can use the example, currently it stops at the undefined command `\begindocument`  but `\input{9_appendix}` also needs to be deleted as we don't have it, and add `bmc_article.bib` with the three entries, so the output shown can be generated.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the three entries in the question.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I have correct it. The correct command is \begin{document}

Comment: I know but it means that the output you show is not generated by the code you posted which is always a bad sign.

Comment: I see what you mean. I have tested the output on my actual research paper, but wanted to share only the usecase example. I will run the output separately as you said. I have attached also the .bst file in the question in case you want to check it, thanks :)

Comment: I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XpZG.png) with all three not using et al

Comment: given your earlier comment I would guess the posted code is not an example of the problem, and you need to cite  a work twice. However the citation style is chosen by the publisher, it makes no sense to use a publisher template then change the style. You could use a different bblography style but the publisher may reject that

Comment: It looks like the template does this intentionaly. If you look at this paper example : shorturl.at/koqtG  , which is the same target journal I am working on, you will find that they do sometimes write the citation in the "firstname et al" format, and other times they put it in the "all author names" format, which remains kinda strange

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance though, Mr David :)

Answer (score 1):

The posted code does not produce the output shown, it makes

[image]

with et al not used.

If you repeat the paragraph you get

[image]

With et al used consistently for repeat citations. This is a deliberate design decision by the publisher to give full information in a first citation and a compressed form later.

You could use a different bibliography style, but the journal publisher may not accept it, the point of using a journal template like this is that the publisher makes the design decisions.